# Symfony2's Form Factory is throwing a warning on an array_replace().  How can I resolve this warning?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm getting the following error on Symfony2:

> Warning: array_replace() [function.array-replace]: Argument #1 is not an array in /home/rackelas/public_html/dev/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php line 236

after adding the following to Acme/Bundle/Form/Type/ContactType.php for validation:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
        'name' => new MinLength(5),
        'email' => new Email(array('message' => 'Invalid email address')),
    ));

    $options['validation_constraint'] = $collectionConstraint;
}
```

source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you install XDebug? It would give you a full stack trace instead of just an error on one line.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that but I'll give it a google search, maybe it will help the next time around. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a `return $options;` to your getDefaultOptions method.

Answer (score 2):

What you are receiving is not an error, it is a warning.

The warning states that the function is looking for an array, but you are passing it a non-array variable.

So FormFactory.php on line 236 is calling `array_replace()` with an argument that is not an array.  That is where you should be looking to resolve this problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't get a notification so I assumed the question remained unanswered. I couldn't figure it out, I tried David Dan's recommendation but I still kept getting the error so I scrapped using the form without a class and went ahead and created an entity for it. It actually turned out better as now I can pull the info from the database to my admin area. Thanks.